# Membership fixed period, not working as expected

Tags: civimember

I want to to create a monthly membership that recurs automatically, but doesn't start until the first of the following month. So if someone signs up January 2nd, they won't be billed until February 1st. Is this possible?

I've setup a membership type with auto-renew required, 1 month duration, fixed period, with fixed period rollover day of 01.

It seems like this should do what I want, and yet when people register, their payment comes through immediately, regardless of what day it is.

Comment: some payment gateways offer features like 'trial' which i know can be used to 'bump' the first payment to a later date (eg using Stripe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed membership type plans, the Fixed Period Start Day and Fixed Period Rollover Day apply solely to the membership start and end dates, ***not*** to the payment date. Copying from the explanation provided when clicking on the Membership Type Plan help bubble:

> If membership duration is specified in years, you will be able to specify the exact month and day for memberships to start. If membership duration is specified in months, memberships will start on the 1st of the current month and run for the number of specified months.

So long as your membership start and end dates follow the examples below, then the feature is functioning as programmed.

- If you have a fixed membership type configured for a Duration of 1 **month** and Fixed Period Rollover Day of 2, someone signing up on on May 22 will have the following membership dates:

  - Member Since: May 22
  - Membership Start: May 1
  - Membership End: June 30
- If you have a fixed membership type configured for a Duration of 1 **year** with a Fixed Period Start Day of Jan. 1 and Fixed Period Rollover Day of Nov. 30, someone signing up on on Dec. 1, 2019 will have the following membership dates:

  - Member Since: Dec. 1, 2019
  - Membership Start: Jan. 1, 2020
  - Membership End: Dec. 31, 2020

Note that the Member Since date is always the date that the membership is submitted - this is because the system is not programmed to handle future memberships. The workaround is to create a membership status rule (e.g. called "Future Membership") with a Start Event = Member Since Date and End Event = Membership Start Date and that should ***not*** be considered a current membership .

Regardless of your membership type configuration, payment will be processed on the day that the membership is submitted. If your payment processor allows for the selection of a payment start date for recurring contributions, you should be able to solicit a customization from an [**expert**](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) that will allow you to set the desired membership start date for ***monthly*** memberships, and then pass the membership start date as the payment start date of the recurring contribution.

Hope this clarifies things!